# How to get around Lightning Web Component no-async-operation

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am looking to have a function be called slightly after an event occurs, however it is hard to create timed events with LWC components.

Here is the code that I'd like to have run slightly slower:

```
handleTabBackward(event){
    if(event.shiftKey && event.key === 'Tab'){
        setTimeout(function(){
            let sendButton = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="sendButtonForSignIn"]');
            sendButton.focus();
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

As of now it only works without the timeout function:

```
handleTabBackward(event){
    if(event.shiftKey && event.key === 'Tab'){
        let sendButton = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="sendButtonForSignIn"]');
        sendButton.focus();
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to delay that chunk of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you use a `function(){}`, the `this` variable is changed in this context. If you want to use the `this` variable, you have to either use:

```js
handleTabBackward(event){
    if(event.shiftKey && event.key === 'Tab'){
        setTimeout(function(){
            let sendButton = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="sendButtonForSignIn"]');
            sendButton.focus();
        }.bind(this), 500);
    }
}
```

(Note the `.bind(this)`)

or:

```js
handleTabBackward(event){
    if(event.shiftKey && event.key === 'Tab'){
        setTimeout(() => {
            let sendButton = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="sendButtonForSignIn"]');
            sendButton.focus();
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Note the use of `() => {}` vs. `function() {}`

Comment: This worked great TY. One thing to note is that the () = > version would not work in IE because anynmous functions are not supported for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/salesforce/eslint-plugin-lwc/issues/13):

> We have observed that, even internally at Salesforce, asynchronous operations are overused and developers use those async operations because they are not aware of component's lifecycle hooks. Because eslint reports an error when using an async operation, developers are required to think twice before using such an API.
>
> While I agree with you that there are plenty of valid use cases (animation, flow control, ...), the eslint rule can always be disabled per line `/* eslint-disable */` if you know that doing an async operation is the right thing to do. If you feel that all the developers on your project have a good understanding of the component lifecycle and how async operations work, you can also disable the rule at the project level in the .eslintrc.
>
> The [no-async-operation](https://github.com/salesforce/eslint-plugin-lwc/blob/master/docs/rules/no-async-operation.md) rule is not here to indicate that those APIs are restricted on the Salesforce platform, but rather as a guardrail for developers as the documentation mention.

In other words, it is allowed, and if you have a valid use case, you can use the appropriate command to override this error, but you should think carefully about if another option is available. You can still deploy your code, but be aware that it is not recommended.